# Size of UIScrollView and Size of Images

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

I have created this scrollview that loads the images dynamically. However I cannot get the images to cover the screen (should adapt to iPhone/iPad) one and one. And the height of the images is also corrupt (see attached image)

What am I doing wrong?

Image

[image]

Source to load images:

```
 for (int i=0; i < numberOfImages; i++) {

        // create image
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat: imageArray[i], i+1];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

        // put image on correct position
        CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
        rect.origin.x = currentX + self.scrollView.frame.size.width/2;
        imageView.frame = rect;

        // update currentX
        currentX += imageView.frame.size.width + self.scrollView.frame.size.width;

        [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(currentX, self.view.frame.size.height);

    self.scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    [self.scrollView release];
```

Comment: Can you please provide a few more details about how do you want the images to be positioned? It looks like you have a Page Control there, so you want the images to be side by side horizontally?

Comment: @pteofil CORRECT! Images are supposed to be centered and only one visible in the uiscrollview should be visible at one moment. Should appear same on both iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++) {

    // create image
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat: imageArray[i], i+1];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

    // put image on correct position
    CGRect rect = self.scrollView.bounds;
    rect.origin.x = currentX;
    imageView.frame = rect;

    // update currentX
    currentX += self.scrollView.frame.size.width;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
}

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(currentX, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

You could also set the scrollView paging property to yes, so it will scroll page by page.

Comment: I had to play around with the images fram and am working to get the images apart and centered but this was what I needed. thanks! Bountry coming up! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a UICollectionView with horizontal scrolling instead of a scrollView, and you can implement the delegate from the collection view to provide cells with the desired dimensions. The implementation would be extremely more simple and straightforward.

Comment: Gotta look into this before I set pteofils answer to the bounty :)